# How to calculate weights between users in network graph using R

Tags: graph, social-networking

I have a network of N users. I have adjacency list of those users. , I want to calculate weights (not just 0/1 to show connectivity) between each user on the basis of their effective edge in the network. So, suppose I have 10 users, I can tell weight of each edge in the connection. I would want the output in NxN Matrix form. Does R has something which can solve my problem?